# Can't persist contract storage values with sputnikdao's educational AssemblyScript version

Tags: nearprotocol

I have cloned the [Sputnikdao-AS-Contract](https://github.com/VitalPointAI/SputnikDao-AS-Contract) repository locally and I am able to build the contract under `sputnikdao-as` folder successfully. However, after deploying it to testnet, when I invoke the init() function with valid parameters, the [call succeeds but the fields are null](https://explorer.testnet.near.org/transactions/5vpfM1UYMeouLZCXDDxSgMo8GTqQfMERa543KBrnw9KB). The values passed in as parameters to init() don't persist. Do I need to modify the code in any way for persistence in contract storage to be enabled?

**Build is successful:**

```
$ node ./compile.js --debug                                                          

> sputnikdao-as@0.0.1 build:debug
> asb --target debug
```

**Deployment to testnet is successful:**

```
$ near dev-deploy ./build/debug/sputnikdao-as.wasm                                   
Starting deployment. Account id: dev-1646462436509-55850829247001, node: https://rpc.testnet.near.org, helper: https://helper.testnet.near.org, file: ./build/debug/sputnikdao-as.wasm
Transaction Id 9Z7NEN31FzS88XLnaHMvQ2j5PS4MZzENAS1DFBFi5wXx
To see the transaction in the transaction explorer, please open this url in your browser
https://explorer.testnet.near.org/transactions/9Z7NEN31FzS88XLnaHMvQ2j5PS4MZzENAS1DFBFi5wXx
Done deploying to dev-1646462436509-55850829247001
```

**However, init() function call doesn't persist values:**

```
$ near call dev-1646462436509-55850829247001 init '{"purpose":"Testing sputnik DAO function calls", "bond":"3", "council":["ed25519:FaEcWe63S4Mwk2pnaaCpL11a8D56hvifUuvfWWkxvmWf", "ed25519:D2E9TfHhxj7r54DAvjMiBxZiJ5XDaaZk19n2C7FWBSjB"], "vote_period":"3", "grace_period":"5"}' --accountId dev-1646462436509-55850829247001
Scheduling a call: dev-1646462436509-55850829247001.init({"purpose":"Testing sputnik DAO function calls", "bond":"3", "council":["ed25519:FaEcWe63S4Mwk2pnaaCpL11a8D56hvifUuvfWWkxvmWf", "ed25519:D2E9TfHhxj7r54DAvjMiBxZiJ5XDaaZk19n2C7FWBSjB"], "vote_period":"3", "grace_period":"5"})
Doing account.functionCall()
Transaction Id 5vpfM1UYMeouLZCXDDxSgMo8GTqQfMERa543KBrnw9KB
To see the transaction in the transaction explorer, please open this url in your browser
https://explorer.testnet.near.org/transactions/5vpfM1UYMeouLZCXDDxSgMo8GTqQfMERa543KBrnw9KB
{
  purpose: null,
  bond: null,
  vote_period: null,
  grace_period: null,
  policy: null,
  council: null,
  proposals: null
}
```

**Double-check with a view function:**

```
$ near view dev-1646462436509-55850829247001  get_purpose                                
View call: dev-1646462436509-55850829247001.get_purpose()
null
```

Comment: be aware that this is not the official source code for SputnikDAO but a version created early in 2021 for educational purposes.  the official source for SputnikDAO is here: https://github.com/near-daos/sputnik-dao-contract/tree/feat/enchance-contract-v2-readme/sputnikdao2

Comment: @amgando Noted, thanks for the pointer. Is the AssemblyScript version a working version though? I can't figure out whether I am doing something wrong or if the AS version needs a local change on my end to work successfully.